# I have deployed my Telegram Bot on Heroku but doesn't work

Tags: heroku, bots, telegram

I can run my telegram bot with Python written on my pc without problems.
I have deployed it on heroku and it says Build successful. But I can not get ant response from it.
What may be the problem?
Here is my bot codes:
https://github.com/SezzR/evradnur-bot

Comment: the link you posted is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the code of below on heroku to run it:

$ heroku ps:scale -a <YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME> worker=1

Then stop it with:

$ heroku ps:scale -a <YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME> worker=0